# how to refresh onBindViewHolder method in fragment

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

i have checkbox in each item of recyclearview, so i want to save state of checkboxes so i am creating on click listner for checkbox in [adapter-class] onbindviewholder  method for store state of checkbox in mysqlite database and then i am retrieving those values and save to checkbox-state

-problem is checkbox_state is refreshing only when i reopen my app

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myviewholder holder, int position) {

checkBox.setOnClickListener(
   new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

     if (checkBox.isChecked() == true){
     database db1 = new database(context);
     db1.update_data_ck( String.valueOf(id.get(getAdapterPosition()) ), "true");
     } 
     else {
     database db1 = new database(context);
     db1.update_data_ck( String.valueOf(id.get(getAdapterPosition()) ),"false");
     }
  }});
}
```

//here id is arraylist

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the code where you are updating the state of checkbox, for each view you must read the state of checkbox from database and set in bindviewholder,

like :
checkBox.setChecked(readCheckBoxStateFromDB())

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save state of checkbox in database than when ever a view create check values and set state of a checkbox
you can also use share preference to store the state
but now recommended way is
you can use Room Real time data update easy and recommended way
SQL Lite too much code write to save state and retrieve state